# How to compare HEAD commit from one branch with HEAD commit from another branch in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have 2 local branches, branch1 and newer_branch1.

branch1 has commit#1 as the HEAD commit and so does newer_branch1, but I don't know if branch1 is actually up to date with newer_branch1, as newer_branch1 has the most recent version of the commit. They also have the same exact commit messages so I can't simply tell they're different commit versions based on commit text.

I tried to view only the HEAD commit diffs with `git diff ID#X..ID#Y` (where ID#X is the SHA ID# of newer_branch1 HEAD commit, and ID#Y is the SHA ID# of branch1) but I am seeing older commits from the git log being diff'd instead.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `git diff ID#X ID#Y` without `..`?

Comment: You can see the commit hash IDs with `git rev-parse`, or of course with `git log`; if the hash IDs match, the two branch names identify the same commit, and if not, they don't. Other than that, as your question is written, all I can say is that you're using "HEAD" (all uppercase) where you should use "head" (lowercase) to refer to the *tip commit* of a branch.